# Will Star Wars VII be a CGI or live action movie?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I've heard Disney is [casting the crew](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/) of the original Star Wars trilogy to make the upcoming sequel. Given the age and outlook of the actors, will they be producing an actual live-action movie? Has this been confirmed anywhere yet?

Comment: I suspect this to be prone to elicit random speculation, but let's see where it goes.

Comment: More interesting: was Episode 1 a CGI or live-action movie?

Comment: What you should be asking: Will there be lens flare?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The short answer is **yes they will be producing a live action** film and **yes, it's been confirmed** on multiple occasions.

In an official quote to Starwars.com, Lucasfilm/Disney have announced the [film crew](http://starwars.com/news/master-filmmaking-team-announced-for-star-wars.html) for Star Wars VII will include;

> Director of photography Dan Mindel, Special effects supervisor Chris
>   Corbould and Visual effects supervisor Roger Guyett

None of whom would be required for an animated feature.

They've also confirmed that

> **Location scouting**, production design, casting, and costume design
>   are underway.

Also, the film has been announced as Live-action in [Variety](http://variety.com/2013/film/news/did-disney-underestimate-fan-demand-for-star-wars-at-d23-expo-1200577194/) and [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/scottmendelson/2013/08/12/thank-you-disney-for-not-spoiling-star-wars-episode-7/).

On top of that, there's a [direct quote](http://uk.eonline.com/news/358713/disney-not-stopping-at-star-wars-7-3-films-and-more-coming) from Disney chief exec Robert Iger in which he describes the upcoming trilogy as part of their

> "**live-action strategy** as a known and loved brand"

**UPDATE : Disney has now [confirmed](http://uk.movies.yahoo.com/confirmed-star-wars-vii-feature-trio-heroes-182900926.html) that principal photography will be taking place at Pinewood Studios, London**

> *"Disney and Lucasfilm are excited to announce that principal photography on Star Wars: Episode VII, directed by J.J. Abrams, will
>   commence May 2014, and will be based at London's historic Pinewood
>   Studios."*

**UPDATE II : [Paparazzi photographs](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/apr/18/star-wars-episode-vii-images-film-set-desert) appear to show part of the set being constructed at one of the primary filming sites in Abu Dhabi.**

[image: Star Wars set]

**UPDATE III : The Producers have released a picture of a clapperboard on their [official twitter feed](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/star-wars-episode-vii-first-704853?utmsource_gravity=&grcc2=d7ec485b1d2e9ccf7d6e74b6e2cda7b7~1400257842375~01b0b9ad501e0c849a822e6124ff0fc2~~1400255940000~598~24~0~0~0~-1~-1~-1~18~24~38~H4sIAAAAAAAAAJ2QvW7dMAyFX6V3uFMgQ9S_sjUoUhSdOxuyRd2r1LYMWYmRhc9eBR26ZCpxFvKA3yF4b22_yq9X8dx1nudwL8vyfpYSK-6lNqzDXNbu3TE09paPXLbeRVywYWQvGDNb8oasYkRc-6hMmRktteYkwFoltbNSGqGlBE_3_8s7WqjsDPVguOejROxWZinXozHLldPyKp9f23qU1zrjeKvhLbf3q_xG4CUQae_IceIw8cmHqDkgn53ywQmBBoRKiadZkJ-TUmGWNkBQOqRowaSQgvAyJRSCiI7c8Ed8ZAoAnAEjvLcWPNfOjHNY95BvW_cNF0ooK7T3HMBycJr6ASTJGE_z73EY_5LGz0gP_0jj56Su70-XX1tnxC8_83aLZb3wS5eGQV8YH0By3l_jPqaE1ssYwShjJqe0mnRAlDE4JeQkA5IzAxg39KC-qOh4mYGFPXeEpxSWA-mj_gBZQImuLwIAAA);**

[image]

**UPDATE IV :** Jarjar Abrams has released a video "from the set of Star Wars 7"

**Update V**

Aerial photographs of the Millennium Falcon and (Luke's?) X-Wing have appeared on the BBC website, apparently taken by a flight instructor

[image]

Comment: Now *that* is a well sourced and definitive answer. +1.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: I agree. My initial scepticism was unwarranted. +1

Comment: JJ Abrams...meh, okay I guess.  My dirty blasphemous secret is that I want a remake the entire Star Wars series sans the George Lucas slapstick. Director...Christopher Nolan.

Comment: +1 for Jarjar Abrams update (also because this answer is wonderful).